# How to use Xamarin.Forms MediaManager library with MVVM to play youtube videos

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I'm trying to get working the MediaManager library playing a couple videos from youtube using MVVM approach.

My idea is to have a single view where initially is loaded a video, once the user watched the first loaded video he can click a button to see another video in the same view.

I can't find many examples on the internet related about how to accomplish this using MVVM, every example I've found uses the codebehind approach but my app is created in full MVVM so I need to get it working like that.

This is what I've done by now.

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Behaviors;assembly=Behaviors"
             xmlns:mediamanager="clr-namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms"
             x:Class="VideoView"
             BindingContext="{Binding VideoViewModel, Source={StaticResource ServiceLocator}}">

    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="Appearing">
            <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageAppearingCommand}" />
        </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <StackLayout Margin="10,60,10,0">

        <Label x:Name="LblMsg"/>

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <mediamanager:VideoView x:Name="TrainingVideoPlayer"
                                    AspectMode="AspectFill"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="progress" HeightRequest="10" Progress="{Binding ProgressStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Image x:Name="ImgPlay"
                           Source="video_play.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PlayTappedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Image x:Name="ImgPause"
                           Source="video_pause.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PauseTappedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Image x:Name="ImgStop"
                           Source="video_stop.png"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StopTappedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
           </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

        <Button x:Name="BtnNext" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel

```
public class VideoViewModel : AppBaseViewModel
{

    //Commands
    public ICommand PageAppearingCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand PlayTappedCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand PauseTappedCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand StopTappedCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand NextCommand { get; set; }

    //Fields
    private double _progressStatus;
    private string youtubevideourl;

    //Properties
    public double ProgressStatus
    {
        get => _progressStatus;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref _progressStatus, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProgressStatus);
            }
        }
    }

    public VideoViewModel()
    {
        PageAppearingCommand = new Command(OnPageAppearing);
        PlayTappedCommand = new Command(OnImgPlay_Tapped);
        PauseTappedCommand = new Command(OnImgPause_Tapped);
        StopTappedCommand = new Command(OnImgStop_Tapped);
        NextCommand = new Command(OnBtnNext_Click);

        youtubevideourl = "https://urloftheyoutubevideo";
    }

    private async void OnPageAppearing()
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();

        //Sets the videoplayer events to control playback status
        CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayingChanged += VideoPlayer_PlayingChanged;
        CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaFinished += VideoPlayer_MediaFinished;
    }

    private async void OnImgPlay_Tapped()
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(youtubevideourl, MediaFileType.Video);
    }

    private async void OnImgPause_Tapped()
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
    }

    private async void OnImgStop_Tapped()
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();
    }

    private void VideoPlayer_PlayingChanged(object sender, PlayingChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ProgressStatus = e.Progress;
        });
    }

    private void VideoPlayer_MediaFinished(object sender, MediaFinishedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some logic
    }

    private async void OnBtnNext_Click()
    {
        //logic to load the next video url
    }
}
```

Using this code I can execute play/pause/stop methods of the MediaManager but nothing happens in the View, I cant even see 1 second of the youtube video.

I will appreciate your help

Note: I installed the MediaManager nuget package in my three projects: Android, iOS and NetStandard library

Note2: One of my requirements is to guarantee as much as possible the user watched the whole video before moving to the next one (the value will be stored in an external DB), so any solution different to this one must follow this requirement

Comment: You can not use MediaManager to play YouTube videos, you would need to use an embedded `WebView`

Comment: @SushiHangover Documentation says it's possible to load remote videos from url

Comment: Remote video streaming Yes, Youtube: No.

Comment: @SushiHangover https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/c47e11beb32eaba2e2bad17eb46fdeec9bde82c5/MediaManager/IMediaManager.cs#L73

Comment: You could use the native Youtube Player API on iOS and Android (it uses the installed Youtube App via  an exposed Service/API), this does of course have usage restrictions. Most apps use the `IFrame` based player as this allows Youtube to serve ads, etc... as it does not have the native player restrictions

Comment: @SushiHangover Where did you get the info saying is not possible to play youtube videos using MediaManager?

Comment: A YouTube url is just not supported, unless you are trying to use a static video url from Google's CDN which is against their TOS (and they are changing all the video streams to actual separate the video and audio into two separate multiple-part/chuck streams, which again are not supported via MediaManager since they are just wrapping the native player)

Comment: MediaManager uses the native video player on each platform, whether that is Android or iOS, and those players do not support streaming from a youtube url. Those urls are Web-based and require you to use the `IFrame` player (which is HTML/JavaScript based). Review the Youtube Iframe api if you wish to embed Youtube videos into a Forms' WebView:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: If you need a "native" player, review the Youtube iOS and Android Player API (you can write Forms' renderers to expose them in a cross-platform manner if needed): https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: @SushiHangover one of my requirements is to be sure as much as possible the user watched the whole video, I think that is not possible using IFrame

Comment: The IFrame does have an API and you can poll to see if the video is playing, etc... There are limitations, based on platform and by Youtube, on what you are allowed to do to with this IFrame (i.e. Auto-starting a video on iOS is against Apple's policy, and is blocked, auto-starting videos on any platform do not count as a youtube "view", lots more, all listed in the IFrame API docs). It really depends on if YouTube (and the available Iframe or native API) meets your apps requirements, otherwise private hosting of those videos and playing them via MediaManager might make more sense.